# add column from a csv file to another one

Tags: python, csv

I want to add the column *"coordinates"* from CSV file named **"section_extract.csv"** to another csv file named **"prev_section.csv"**. The two CSV files have a commun columns named *"NOM"*.

[this is how the csv file called "section_extract.csv" looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO6W3.png)

[this is how the csv file called "prev_section.csv" looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrZwW.png)

What makes that a bit difficult for me is that the **"coordinates"** must be assigned by **"NOM"**. I should fill the csv file **"prev_section.csv"** with the coordinates correponding to every *"NOM"*. For example : if we pick *NOM = "PA62.565"* I need to fill the coordinates corresponding to that one into csv file **"prev_section.csv"**.

[Finally the result should look like Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VByWz.png)

You can find the 2 CSV files here : https://mega.nz/folder/FvxU2LzY#2NopozzSqgCOVeBezyiAcA

Comment: Please, in order to make it easy to help, paste some CSV rows as text instead of just a screen capture. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think you should take a look at [pandas.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) or [pandas.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: CSVs can be visualized using [markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I have added some comments to make it self-explanatory:

```
import csv

# We create a map (dict) having NOM as key and coords as value
with open('section_extract.csv') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    coord_map = {row[5]: row[1] for row in csv_reader}

# We extract the rows of the prev_section.csv file
with open('prev_section.csv') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    rows = [row for row in csv_reader]

# We will use this variable to keep track of the last read
# NOM, because in prev_section.csv the NOM is empty for some
# rows and it is meant to reference the last one
last_nom = None

# We add to the header a new column called 'coordinates'
rows[0].append('coordinates')

# We iterate the rows of prev_section.csv and add the coords
# values given a NOM, using the previously created map (dict)
for i in range(1, len(rows)):
    row = rows[i]

    # IMPORTANT: we update the last NOM every time we find
    #            a row that contains a value at this column
    if row[0]:
        last_nom = row[0]

    row.append(coord_map.get(last_nom))

# We finally write in a 'prev_section2.csv' the same values
# as the original file but with the new 'coordinates' column
with open('prev_section2.csv', 'w') as file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
    csv_writer.writerows(rows)
```

**SIDENOTE:** It could be done without creating the `rows` list, and reiterating through it, but I think it is better to be explicit here. If you need a more optimal solution you just have to ask for it :)

Comment: Thank you so much Sherlock Bourne, it's working :)